# Preventing mouse click event from firing on elements on a particular z-index

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to disable onclick events from firing for events on a particular z-index, besides running through all elements and setting their onclick to function(){} if they are on that z-index?

Edit:

At this point, the best I can come up with is to hook each function in the DOM tree recursively:

```
function preventZIndexClicks(elem) {
    // ensure not a text node

    if(!elem.popupflag) { elem.popupflag = 1; 
        if(elem.onclick) { var temp = elem.onclick; 
        elem.onclick = function(e) { 
            if(g_threshold > elem.style.zIndex)  
                return; 
            temp(e);}
        } 
    }

    // Call recusively on elem.childNodes 
}
```

Of course, then I would have to deal with the rather annoying IE issues with setting custom properties on DOM elements...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check the z-index in the event and let it bubble through the rest.

```
function onclick(e) {
    if(this.style.zIndex == 10) return;
    //do stuff
}
```

**EDIT:**
Just to clarify how i mean, consider this:

```
<div id="div1" style="background-color: red;width:100px;height:100px;z-index:1">
    <div id="div2" style="background-color: green;width:50px;height:50px;z-index:2">
        <div id="div3" style="background-color: blue;width:25px;height:25px;z-index:3">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this javascript:

```
var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
var div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
var div3 = document.getElementById("div3");
bind(div1,"click",click);
bind(div2,"click",click);
bind(div3,"click",click);

function click(e) {
    if(this.style.zIndex == 2) return;
    alert(this.style.backgroundColor);
}

function bind(element,event,callback){
    var onevent="on"+event;
    if(element.addEventListener)
        element.addEventListener(event,callback,false);
    else if(element.attachEvent)
        element.attachEvent(onevent,callback);
    else{
        var e=element[onevent];
        element[onevent]=function(){
            var h=e.apply(this,arguments),cbk=callback.apply(this,arguments);
            return h==undefined?cbk:(cbk==undefined?h:cbk&&h);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the click will work as follow:

```
click red: -> alert "red"
click green: -> alert "red"
click blue: -> alert "blue" -> alert "red"
```

As you see the green element with z-index:2; will not "fire" the event

Comment: I would have to add that to each of my onClick functions, and I am not sure that I want to do that.

Comment: Then I cant think of any other way than you example. Would be fairly easy with jQuery or equivalent library. Not efficient thought.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent the onclick from firing inside of a mousedown event?

Comment: I don't see how that will solve your problem. But no, not that I'm aware of.

Comment: @wazz3r in your current solution `this` will be the `window` object not the element that was clicked.

Comment: 'this' will refer to the element that called the event.

Comment: As for the being easy with jQuery, I was under that the impression that jQuery implements common higher level functionality on javascript, which would imply that javscript itself could handle it.

Comment: You are correct. I was speaking of "running through all elements and setting their onclick to function(){} if they are on that z-index?", witch is fairly easy with jQuery and a bit trickier with nativ javascript.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onclick = function(e)
{
    var targetElem;

    if (!e)
    {
        var e = window.event;
    }

    if (e.target)
    {
        targetElem = e.target;
    }
    else if (e.srcElement)
    {
        targetElem = e.srcElement;
    }

    if (targetElem.nodeType == document.TEXT_NODE)
    {
        targetElem = targetElem.parentNode;
    }

    if (targetElem.style.zIndex == 100)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: I attempted something like this, but from what I was reading, while you can set the window.onclick, and it will be called (even if the element has an onclick function, due to event propagation) along with any onclicks as it moves up the tree. But the problem remains: the original onclick will still be called.

Comment: At this point, the best I can come up with is to hook each function in the DOM tree, recursively:    function preventZIndexClicks(elem) {
 // ensure not a text node
 
 if(!elem.popupflag) {
  elem.popupflag = 1;
  
  if(elem.onclick) {
   var temp = elem.onclick;
   elem.onclick = function(e) { 
    if(g_threshold > elem.style.zIndex)
     return;
    temp(e);
   }
  }
  
 // Call recusively on elem.childNodes
}

Of course, then I would have to deal with the rather annoying IE issues with setting custom properties on DOM elements...

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery:

```
$('*').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.css('z-index') < g_threshold) {
        $this.unbind('click'); //unbinds all click handlers from a DOM element
        $this.click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    }
});
```

this is basically like what you do, but requires no additional attributes or whatever else you dislike. If you need to leave, say, textbox untouched, then use `$('*').not('input:text')`

Comment: The only issue with this is once the popup is destroyed, and the original page restored, each of the effected elements will have no onclick().